# Issue Drawing a Variable to screen

Tags: c#, xna, tostring

So as mentioned above I am trying to Draw a variable to screen in XNA. I understand this has been requested a few times and have gone through those posts but I'm not having any luck in getting it to work. Here is what I have.

```
SpriteFont _Font1;
float power = 0.0f;
Vector2 powerPos = new Vector2(100, 100);
```

(LoadContent)

```
_Font1 = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Font1");
```

(Draw)

```
SpriteBatch.DrawString(_Font1, power.ToString(), powerPos, Color.White);
```

It's probably not a surprise to you to say that I'm new to this however I understand it's an issue with the whole 'power.ToString()' section, as far as I know the others are fine.

edit: my error is 'an object reference is required to access non-static field'

Comment: What is powerPos?  Where do you declare it?

Comment: powerPos is a Vector2 I have declared for the position of the text, I'm fairly sure this is ok however I have declared it in the Main using         Vector2 powerPos = new Vector2(100, 100);

Comment: In the Main, as in your Program.cs?

Comment: In order to access from the static main class, you need to specify your Game object, and the variable also needs to be static (Game1.powerPos).  But the right way to do this, is to move your drawing position into the Game class instead.  Initiate and use it there instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help, solved it, turns out it was a lot easier than first thought.. I think the Programming Pixies fixed it when I went to make some food! (Check Edit)

Comment: @Rich If you have found a solution to your problem you should post it as an *answer to the question* rather than as an edit to the question itself.

Comment: I tried and it said that I couldn't do this for another 12 hours or something and that is why I edited it, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20224902/3) the author found this solution:

> simply changing
>
> ```
> SpriteBatch.DrawString(_Font1, power.ToString(), powerPos, Color.White);
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> spriteBatch.DrawString(_Font1, power.ToString(), powerPos, Color.White);
> ```
>
> (yes that's correct, changing the uppercase 'S' to a lowercase 's')
>
> fixed the problem and I now have my float point printed to the screen.